# How to handle database duplicates on C# app?

Tags: c#, sql

In my program I have 3 major functions INSERT UPDATE DELETE, the project is about creating a Machine Profile in the database updating it and deleting it.

So far my code is working but I have some issues with duplicates, when I want to update in my code I do check if a profile already exists so it want duplicate it but here when erver I update it duplicate the record, and when I delete that does the same thing.

This is a link to a video that express my issue: https://vimeo.com/317221805

Here's my code :

```
private void Sauv_Btn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cnString);

        using (SqlCommand check_User_Name = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Fiche_Machine] WHERE ([N_SERIE] = @N_SERIE)", con))
        {
            con.Open();
            check_User_Name.Parameters.AddWithValue("@N_SERIE", textBoxNumSer.Text);

            using (SqlDataReader reader = check_User_Name.ExecuteReader())
            {
                reader.Read();
                int count = reader.GetInt32(0);
            }
            int UserExist = (int)check_User_Name.ExecuteScalar();

            if (MessageBox.Show("Voulez-vous sauvgarder la modification de cette fiche client ?", "Sauvgarde fiche client...", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                try
                {

                    if (UserExist == 0)
                    {

                        MessageBox.Show("Le Client n'existe pas Renseigner le numero de Serie UNIQUE obligatoirement");

                    }
                    else if (UserExist > 0)

                    {
                        //Fihce Machine-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


                        Methodes.dt.Rows[rowId]["N_SERIE"] = textBoxNumSer.Text.Trim();
                        Methodes.dt.Rows[rowId]["TYPE_DE_MACHINE"] = textBoxTpMch.Text.Trim();
                        Methodes.dt.Rows[rowId]["N_MOTEUR"] = textBoxNumMtr.Text.Trim();
                        Methodes.dt.Rows[rowId]["PONT_AVANT"] = textBoxPnAv.Text.Trim();
                        Methodes.dt.Rows[rowId]["PONT_ARRIERE"] = textBoxPnAr.Text.Trim();
                        Methodes.dt.Rows[rowId]["BOITE_DE_VITESSE"] = textBoxBtVit.Text.Trim();
                        Methodes.dt.Rows[rowId]["DISTRIBUTEUR_AVANT"] = textBoxDisAv.Text.Trim();




                        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                        Methodes.adap.Update(Methodes.dt);

                        MessageBox.Show("Fiche Sauvgarder avec succés");
                    }

                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }        

            Form1 form1 = new Form1();
            form1.LoadData();


            }
    }

    private void Vld_Btn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cnString);

        using (SqlCommand check_User_Name = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Fiche_Machine] WHERE ([N_SERIE] = @N_SERIE)", con))
        {
            con.Open();
            check_User_Name.Parameters.AddWithValue("@N_SERIE", textBoxNumSer.Text);

            using (SqlDataReader reader = check_User_Name.ExecuteReader())
            {
                reader.Read();
                int count = reader.GetInt32(0);
            }
            int UserExist = (int)check_User_Name.ExecuteScalar();

            if (UserExist == 0)
            {

                try
                {
                    if (textBoxNumSer.Text.Trim() == ("N_SERIE"))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("N°SERIE Existant vous pouvez le modifier ou le supprimer");
                    }

                    if (textBoxNumSer.Text.Trim() == "")
                    {

                        MessageBox.Show("Remplissez les champs vides.... et renseigner le numero de Serie UNIQUE obligatoirement");

                    }
                    else

                    {

                        DataRow dr;

                        dr = Methodes.dt.NewRow();


                        //Fihce Machine-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


                        dr["N_SERIE"] = textBoxNumSer.Text.Trim();
                        dr["TYPE_DE_MACHINE"] = textBoxTpMch.Text.Trim();
                        dr["N_MOTEUR"] = textBoxNumMtr.Text.Trim();
                        dr["PONT_AVANT"] = textBoxPnAv.Text.Trim();
                        dr["PONT_ARRIERE"] = textBoxPnAr.Text.Trim();
                        dr["BOITE_DE_VITESSE"] = textBoxBtVit.Text.Trim();
                        dr["DISTRIBUTEUR_AVANT"] = textBoxDisAv.Text.Trim();


                        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



                        Methodes.dt.Rows.Add(dr);

                        Methodes.adap.Update(Methodes.dt);

                        try
                        {

                            MessageBox.Show("Fiche Sauvgarder avec succés");
                        }
                        catch (SqlException ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        }

                    }



                }

                catch (Exception ex)

                {

                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

                }

                con.Close();

            }
            else

            {

                MessageBox.Show("Ce Numero de Serie existe déjà entrez un nouveau svp");
            }
        }

                Form1 form1 = new Form1();
                form1.LoadData();
    }



    private void Supp_Btn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cnString);

        using (SqlCommand check_User_Name = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Fiche_Machine] WHERE ([N_SERIE] = @N_SERIE)", con))
        {
            con.Open();
            check_User_Name.Parameters.AddWithValue("@N_SERIE", textBoxNumSer.Text);

            using (SqlDataReader reader = check_User_Name.ExecuteReader())
            {
                reader.Read();
                int count = reader.GetInt32(0);
            }
            int UserExist = (int)check_User_Name.ExecuteScalar();

            if (UserExist > 0)
            {

                try
                {

                    if (textBoxNumSer.Text.Trim() == "")
                    {

                        MessageBox.Show("La fiche est vide !! Veuillez Selectionner une fiche à supprimer");

                    }
                    else

                    {
                        try

                        {
                            if (MessageBox.Show("êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer ?", "Suppression...", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                            {

                                Methodes.dt.Rows[rowId].Delete();

                                Methodes.adap.Update(Methodes.dt);

                                MessageBox.Show("Fiche Supprimer avec succés");
                            }
                        }

                        catch (Exception ex)

                        {

                            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

                        }

                        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
                        form1.LoadData();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)

                {

                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest filtering that code down to the smallest failing example. I might mean you have to try out what you are attempting in a console app or similar. You might also find while doing this exercise to improve the quality of your question, you find a great solution

Comment: I would also suggest using an RDBMS while interacting with a SQL database. There is a small performance hit, but will help make your code much cleaner. Take a look at EntityFramework from Microsoft. It's good enough that it is used in countless production systems that deal with sizeable load.

Comment: @tigerswithguitars thank you for your suggestion,i'm sorry i don't have a very good english i don't know how to expresse myself in a way that my question will be good as my expression in french

Comment: @Jimmy: You are calling database directly on button click? Anyway, why dont you handle insert/update (upsert) in a single stored procedure?

Comment: In your eaxmple there are a few references to `Methodes.adap` and `Methodes.dt`, this is not detailed in your example, so it's quite hard to know what is happening here.

Comment: @tigerswithguitars this is a link  https://vimeo.com/317221805   to a screen recorde that shows the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a user exists or not, you can just use

`if(reader.HasRows)
   user exists
 else
   user doesn't exist`

Hope this can help